# Monitor if there's a fullscreen app starting?

Tags: xorg

I run workrave on my computer, when I play fullscreen games like warzone2100, it would like this program to be killed automatically and restart when the full-screen app quits.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you could use *Devil's Pie* for the killing and a cronjob polling for those running fullscreen applications, (re)starting workrave if none is found